# How do I delete a record from a table that has a foreign key in other table using spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two entities in my spring boot project:

1. User entity - (Table name - individual)
2. Task entity - (Table name - task)

I have used the @OneToMany relationship from User to task. The mapping is bi-directional.
I am using PostgreSql as my database. The "individual" table has a foreign key in the "task" table.

I wish to delete a user and his corresponding tasks. I have used the cascade type as CascadeType.ALL but I keep getting this error:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "individual" violates foreign key constraint "fkhxb8babfh6k6w52m1s0nlphca" on table "task"
Detail: Key (user_id)=(3) is still referenced from table "task".

How should I delete the user and his corresponding tasks?

The User entity :

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "individual")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int userId;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role = Role.USER;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Activity activity = Activity.ACTIVE;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Task> tasks;
 }
```

Task entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int taskId;

    private String taskName;

    private int priority;

    private String taskDescription;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status = Status.PENDING;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;

}
```

The method I wrote to delete the user:

```
`@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM INDIVIDUAL WHERE user_id = :userId",nativeQuery = true)
void deleteUser(int userId);`
```

Answer (score 0):

add this `orphanRemoval=true` to `@OneToMany` annotation

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Task> tasks;
```